# How to set Policy conditions in Java AWS S3 SDK presigned url

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-java

I use Java AWS S3 SDK to presign my requests. I have the following code:

```
var request = new GeneratePresignedUrlRequest(bucketName, filename)
        .withMethod(method)
        .withExpiration(expiration());

// do something with request

return s3Client.generatePresignedUrl(request);
```

What I need to write in place of comment to add custom conditions like `content-length-range`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For browser-based POST uploads to S3, the AWS Java SDK doesn't provide a way to generate pre-signed URLs with conditions. There's an open [feature request](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2/issues/1493) to add this to the v2 SDK. Note that the PHP, Node.js, and Python SDKs do all provide this feature.

For regular HTTP PUT pre-signed URLs, you can't apply content length restrictions to pre-signed URLs. You *can* place [conditions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-creating-signed-url-custom-policy.html#private-content-custom-policy-statement-values) using a [custom policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-creating-signed-url-custom-policy.html#private-content-custom-policy-statement) but that only supports:

- DateLessThan
- DateGreaterThan
- IpAddress

If you need to deal with objects outside of a given size range then you could potentially do that in AWS Lambda, *after* the object has been uploaded.

Comment: Official [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-HTTPPOSTConstructPolicy.html) says I can . And [php s3 sdk](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/s3-presigned-post.html) has this feature (`$options` variable in this official example). So did the java aws sdk miss it?

Comment: Ah, you're referring to pre-signed POSTs from a browser. Interestingly, as you say, it doesn't look like the Java SDK (v1 or v2) has a generatePresignedPost method at all, while PHP, Node.js, and Python SDKs do. There is an outstanding [feature request](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2/issues/1493) to add this to the v2 Java SDK.